# Angular: Add class to html element inside a CDK Portal

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk, viewchild

I have an app with Angular12 and the Angular Material CDK.

I am adding a template into a CDK Portal, the template is this:

```
<ng-template #templatePortalContent>
     <div class="editable" #newFormField>
         stuff            
     </div>
</ng-template>
```

I need to add a class dynamically to the `#newFormField` item and can't figure out how to access it.  Normally, if this was a regular ng-template such as `#addressBlock` I can use

```
 @ViewChild('addressBlock') addressBlock: ElementRef;
 this.addressBlock.nativeElement.classList.add('editingActive');
```

However, this does not work and throws an error

```
 @ViewChild('newFormField') newFormField: ElementRef;
 this.newFormField.nativeElement.classList.add('editingActive');
```

I figure because the `newFormField` is inside the `#templatePortalContent` template which was inserted into the portal.

How do I refer to the inner element?

Comment: I may have missed something, but I kept getting the element after the portal not the one in it.

Comment: Did you try `[ngClass]`?

Answer (score 1):

That template will be able to access component properties from where it's declared. The `ViewChild` will also be accessible once the template is rendered (I'm pretty sure )

```js
<ng-template #templatePortalContent>
     <div [ngClass]="editableClass" #newFormField>
         stuff            
     </div>
</ng-template>

// In the component
public editableClass = 'editable'
```